# -maxdepth option after a non-option AND find: paths must precede expression

Tags: linux

Hope someone can help with this:

Am trying to delete session files on /tmp with this command:

```
find /tmp -name 'sess_*' -user Username -maxdepth 1 $CMD {} \;
```

but I got these errors:

> find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a
>   non-option argument -name, but options are not positional (-maxdepth
>   affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after
>   it).  Please specify options before other arguments.
>
> ```
> find: paths must precede expression Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
> ```

I looked for solutions over the web but could not find any. I have deleted other tmp files with other commands and wonder if that affected some volume or socket.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`find` has three types of options: options that are used to match files (e.g. `-name`, `-user`), options that specify actions to perform on the matched files (`-print`, `-exec`), and options that control the overall behavior of the command (e.g. `-maxdepth`, `-xdev`). The third type must be put before the other two. So it should be:

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name 'sess_*' -user Username -exec $CMD {} \;
```

Comment: Ah I see, I already tried that but missed the -exec part. Thanks Barmar.The command went thru but every file ends with Permission Denied. I think because am deleting sessions to my username account since /tmp has appropriate permissions: drwxrwxrwt 4 root root 1168384 Sep 15 17:21

Comment: Never mind! access was denied for files owned by root only, but others owned by admin were deleted silently.It does not echo anything when deletion is successful. Thank you all.

Comment: If you want it to echo something when it finds a matching file, use the -print option.

Comment: it's bizarre that I can take a working "find" with something "sh -c" in the exec and it works, but I change one command passed to the shell and suddenly it throws this error!

Comment: @Michael Sounds like a quoting problem to me. Note that quotes aren't processed when expanding `$CMD`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash