# Setting an argument with bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I frequently run a simple bash command:

```
rpm -Uvh --define "_transaction_color 3" myPackage.rpm
```

which works properly.

But now I'm trying to script it into a bash file, and make it more flexible:

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTALL_CMD=rpm
INSTALL_OPT="-Uvh --define '_transaction_color 3'"

${INSTALL_CMD} ${INSTALL_OPT} myPackage.rpm
```

However, this keeps generating the error:

```
error: Macro % has illegal name (%define)
```

The error is coming from how `--define` and the quoted `_transaction_color` is handled.
I've tried a variety of escaping, different phrasing, even making `INSTALL_OPT` an array, handled with `${INSTALL_OPT[@]}`.

So far, my attempts have not worked.
Clearly, what I want is extremely simple.  I'm just not sure how to accomplish it.

How can I get bash to handle my `--define` argument properly?

Comment: You have tried `INSTALL_OPT='-Uvh --define _transaction_color 3'`, right?

Comment: @sampson-chen:  Tried that.  "error: Macro %_transaction_color has empty body".

Comment: This is because bash reads your arguments as `-Uvh` and `--define` and `'_transaction_color` and `3'`. You **must** use an array in this case (as shown below in Barmar's answer): `INSTALL_OPT=(-Uvh --define '_transaction_color 3')`. Then `${INSTALL_CMD} "${INSTALL_OPT[$@]}" myPackage.rpm` works (with double quotes, as he mentionned).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that quotes are not processed after variable substitution. So it looks like you're trying to define a macro named `'_transaction_color`.

Try using an array:

```
INSTALL_OPT=(-Uvh --define '_transaction_color 3')
```

then:

```
"$INSTALL_CMD" "${INSTALL_OPT[@]}" myPackage.rpm
```

It's important to put `${INSTALL_OPT[@]}` inside double quotes to get the requoting.

Comment: I will only `+1` if you edit your post and remove the `evil` thing. It's terrible! Just leave the one with the array, as it is the only good practice!

Comment: Eval is evil if you're using untrusted user input. If you're using it with your own data, it's not so bad.

Comment: +1 for the array answer -- it's the only way to properly handle multiple words that may contain whitespace.

Comment: Yes, or `echo "$CMD $OPT blahblah" | /bin/bash`... Is this less *evil* than `eval` @gniourf_gniourf?

Comment: @F.Hauri It's more evil if you think running unnecessary processes is bad.

Comment: @Barmar How could you think: *unnecessary*? While *evil* mean *dangerous*, the `eval` command put everything to the current environment, where the fork (`|sh`) ensure to leave you current enviroment unmodified. So if there is a difference, sometime the fork could be necessary (depending on *what you do*)... But at all, I think that *fork to sh* is at same level of security risk than *eval*.

Comment: @Barmar, is surrounding `${INSTALL_OPT[@]}` with double-quotes enable requoting or does it prevent the variable substitution from word-splitting?  Honest question, not sure if last sentence of [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)  is applicable.

Comment: @Nate It performs re-quoting. This is explained in [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays): If the word is double-quoted, ... `${name[@]}` expands each element of name to a separate word.

Answer (score -1):

It might be a bash issue with word splitting on space:

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

INSTALL_CMD=rpm
INSTALL_OPT='-Uvh'
INSTALL_OPT_DEFINE='--define _transaction_color 3'

${INSTALL_CMD} ${INSTALL_OPT} ${INSTALL_OPT_DEFINE} myPackage.rpm
```

Comment: I suspect `--define` requires the macro name and value to be in a single argument, so this won't work.

Comment: @Barmar Good point, I wasn't too sure about that part; updated my answer.

Comment: @sampson-chen:  Tried setting IFS and breaking up the options as you describe.   Result:  "-Uvh: unknown option".   (I don't understand why... but thats the error I got)

Comment: @abelenky: Try removing the quotes around `INSTALL_OPT='-Uvh'` (or using double-quotes). Also, I used backticks instead of single-quotes in my original answer by mistake, in case you copy and pasted anything.

Comment: I saw the back-ticks, and assumed you meant regular-ticks (but I tried it both ways to be sure).   It looks like @Barmar's answer works; thanks for the effort.