# Alert!: Unsupported URL scheme! error when sending bulk sms using lynx

Tags: linux, bash

Team kindly help on the error Alert!: Unsupported URL scheme! when snding bulk sms in linux bash script. the lynx command works fine for static URL. This is what i have got below

```
#!/bin/bash
a="lynx -dump 'http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?from=8005&to="
b="&username=tester&password=foobar&smsc=smsc1&text=Test+mt+update'"
for i in cat numbers.txt;do $a$i$b;echo sent $i; done;
```

numbers

```
258909908780
256789123456
676675234789
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces around the numbers? Have you tried `echo $a$i$b` ?

Comment: Are you missing backticks or `$()` around `cat numbers txt`? Is that a copying error or in the real script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the single quote before `http:`. Quotes are not processed after expanding variables, so it's being sent literally to `lynx`. There's no `'http` URL scheme, hence the error message.

Remove the quotes before `http:` and after `+update`.

```
#!/bin/bash
a="lynx -dump http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?from=8005&to="
b="&username=tester&password=foobar&smsc=smsc1&text=Test+mt+update"
for i in $(cat numbers.txt);do $a$i$b;echo sent $i; done;
```

For more information about this, see

[Setting an argument with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash)

Comment: What's the problem with `+`?

Comment: But not in the script?

Comment: And/or don't put the command in a variable. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: The command lynx -dump 'http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?from=8005&to=256772575818&username=tester&password=foobar&smsc=smsc1&text=Sunday+Yes+But+Even+anytime.'  works fine with response 0: Accepted for delivery and msg is sent, but when i modify the script with susgestions u advised i get error Number(s) has/have been denied by white- and/or black-lists. now this is strange. But one number works fine, the + is to put spaces in the message

Comment: You need to put quotes when you write the command normally. You _don't_ need the quotes when the command is coming from a variable.