# mv command works individually on command line but not through script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a fodler that contains file names that have spaces in them.

I have made a script that replaces the spaces and creates the new file name with _ instead of " " (space) and ran the mv command in the for loop.

This has not worked in script and giving me the below message.

```
   Usage: mv [-I] [ -d | -e] [-i | -f] [-E{force|ignore|warn}] [--] src target
   or: mv [-I] [-d | -e] [-i | -f] [-E{force|ignore|warn}] [--] src1 ... srcN directory
```

But if i debug the shell script and extract the mv command individually and run it,it does work fine without any issues.

The command that is generated looks like

```
   mv "abc  ddd eee.txt" abc_ddd_eee.txt
```

Could you please advise why the command when typed on unix box worked fine and not via script ?

Entire script:

```
     for i in * 
      do 
       v1=$(echo $i|sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' )
       v2=$(echo $v1|sed 's/ /_/g'|
             awk -F "[-.]" '{print $2,"_",$1,".",$3}'|
             sed 's/ //g'|
             sed -e 's/^_//g' -e 's/"$//g'|
             sed 's/"//2' )        
       mv $v1 $v2

      done
```

Comment: What does your shell script (the relevant part, anyway) look like?

Comment: Actually my script does a lot.for i in *
   do
   v1=`echo $i|sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g'`
   v2=`echo $v1|sed 's/ /_/g'|awk -F "[-.]" '{print $2,"_",$1,".",$3}'|sed 's/ //g'|sed -e 's/^_//g' -e 's/"$//g'|sed 's/"//2'`
mv $v1 $v2
   done

Comment: Like I said, show the *relevant* part; we can't debug a script we can't see.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're putting quotes in a variable. Quotes aren't processed when expanding variables.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash

Comment: try using '' single quotes around name with spaces.

Comment: @GRC Why do you think that would work differently from double quotes? The only difference between them is if there are variables or command expansions in the string.

Comment: True,i suspected the same @Barmar and have echo'ed that mv command to another seperate file and tried to run that file explicitly.same issue

Comment: @Barmar,I couldnt get the link that you shared linked with my issue.

Comment: I have seen this happen where you would do a shell script with two spaces inside string literal, 2 spaces would collapse into one and it would not work. hen used single quotes you are telling shell do not touch this string.

Comment: The error message means that the command is seeing more than 2 arguments. It's not complaining that the file isn't found.

Comment: @user2075017 If you want me to reopen the question, you need to post your code so we can show how to correct it.

Comment: @user2075017 Post it in the question, not in a comment, so it can be formatted readably.

Comment: Posted the code in readable format @Barmar

Comment: Understanding the difference between syntactic quotes and literal ones would go a long distance towards preventing this from happening in the future.

Comment: Also, all the messing with awk and sed (and echo) is completely unnecessary (and harmful; every time you run `echo $foo`, the value in `foo` is split on IFS, globs in the resulting strings are expanded, etc; `echo "$foo"` is better, but still much worse than doing using native string manipulation primitives).

Comment: ...re: "native string manipulation", see BashFAQ #100: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100. Alternately, you could describe in English what this mess of ugly code is supposed to actually accomplish, and we could suggest a better way to achieve that desired end.

Comment: BashFAQ #50 is also very relevant, in terms of the "why" behind your failure: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: (to explain the "why" a bit differently: Syntactic quotes are parsed *before* parameter expansion occurs; thus, quotes *within* an expanded parameter are treated as data, not syntax. This is actually a desirable characteristic for security reasons -- allowing data to be treated as syntax is the fast track to an injection attack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In native bash, with no external tools other than `mv` itself:

```
for i in *; do
    # change all spaces to underscores
    v2=${i// /_}

    # split into pieces on . and _ characters, and reassemble after 
    IFS='._' read -r first second rest <<<"$v2" && {
      v2="${second}_${first}.${rest}"
    }

    # remove any leading underscore
    v2=${v2#_}

    # rename
    mv -- "$i" "$v2"
done
```

This is vastly more efficient than setting up a new pipeline running `sed` and `awk` once for each filename processed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable guidance

Comment: @Charles that's such a cool trick with `var=${a//b/c}`, upvoted already. Looks like I can stop abusing sed and awk for all substitutions. What is that operation called so I can look up the reference for more things to learn. Found it: [Parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: @Donbhupi, *nod*; http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe is another good reference. Awk is actually quite a bit faster than bash for processing big streams, but if you're only doing one line at a time (or fewer than hundreds in total), the startup overhead is killer. Often, it makes sense just to write a text-processing script in pure awk, with no bash or sed involved.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to add quotes around the name, just quote the variables. Do:

```
for i in * 
do 
   v2=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/ /_/g' | awk -F "[-.]" '{print $2,"_",$1,".",$3}' | sed 's/^_//')     
   mv "$i" "$v2"
done
```

Comment: I'd suggest `printf '%s\n' "$i"` rather than `echo "$i"` -- what if a file is named `-n`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable guidance.It worked :)

Comment: But still not sure ,whats wrong in my code..and whats making it not work :(