# set variable name containing '>' in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have to use a bash script (I'm not familiar with bash) for submitting a HPC job. The job-submission script template sets the command and options and then combines them in the end:

```
input="file_name"
name="simulation1"

application=my_app
options="in=$input.h5 out=$name.h5 param1=foo"

cmd="$application $options"
```

this all works okay, i.e. `eval $cmd` executes

```
my_app in=$input.h5 out=$name.h5 param1=foo
```

until I need the character '>' in the options. In particular, I want to add the option `absrad="mass>1?H:0"`, but if I simply set

```
options="in=$input.h5 out=$name.h5 param1=foo absrad=mass>1?H:0"
```

then bash truncates that at the '>', so that `eval $cmd` executes

```
my_app in=$input.h5 out=$name.h5 param1=foo absrad=mass
```

instead. How to fix that such that `eval $cmd` executes

```
my_app in=$input.h5 out=$name.h5 param1=foo absrad="mass>1?H:0"
```

EDIT. Note that this is similar to, but not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash), where a single-quoted argument is the problem. Moreover, the answers there only consider solutions using an array for the options. I would like alternatives w/o array.

Comment: doesn't bash have a standard escape character? like "\>"

Comment: or single quotes might also work

Comment: Is your command called like `$cmd` or `"$cmd"` because the latter should work.

Comment: Does `\>` fix the issue? Do you have `1?H:0` in the directory after you ran the script?

Comment: FYI - `eval` is not truncating per se, but scanning the string and performing variable substitution and when it gets to the `'>'` it sees the redirection character and will create a file called `'1?H:0'`.  Then it passes the line to the shell for execution. Another reason to avoid using eval which can be dangerous if the variables it is operating on can be manipulated.

Comment: I should have said `eval` can be dangerous if the variables it is operating on can be manipulated to contain commands.  Consider this: param1="ls -l";options=$param1;eval $options.  Now imagine something more devious then a `ls -l` as a command. I found this post with alternatives but do a little searching, you'll find safer ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: @Barmar It's not really an (exact) dupe and the answers provided (one by you) are rather narrow.

Comment: They don't have to be "exact" duplicates, as long as the answers show how to solve the same problem. It's very rare that questions exactly duplicate each other, but they're the same idea.\

Comment: By closing this question you deprive the chance for an alternative (to arrays) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use an array for options:

```
declare -a options=("in=$input.h5" "out=$name.h5" "param1=foo" "absrad=\"mass>1?H:0\"");
declare -a cmd=(my_app "${options[@]}");
```

Then when you want to expand `cmd` the following should give you the correct expansion:

```
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Additionally, this gets rid of the need to use `eval`, which I tend to avoid whenever possible.