# What is the meaning of "${psql[@]}" in this script?

Tags: bash

I came across a [script](https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/blob/master/11-2.5/alpine/initdb-postgis.sh#L9) that is supposed to set up postgis in a docker container, but it references this `"${psql[@]}"` command in several places:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Perform all actions as $POSTGRES_USER
export PGUSER="$POSTGRES_USER"
# Create the 'template_postgis' template db
"${psql[@]}" <<- 'EOSQL'
CREATE DATABASE template_postgis;
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';
EOSQL
```

I'm guessing it's supposed to use the `psql` command, but the command is always empty so it gives an error. Replacing it with `psql` makes the script run as expected. Is my guess correct?

Edit: In case it's important, the command is being run in a container based on `postgres:11-alpine`.

Comment: There's supposed to be code before this that sets `psql` to an array containing the command and its arguments.

Comment: @Barmar `psql` is a command from the installed program, but I don't see anywhere it is set in the script I linked at the top of the post. Do you think it's an error in the script?

Comment: Yeah, the script seems to be missing that. Maybe they expect you to add it, but they don't say so in the documentation.

Comment: It could be that this script is intended to be sourced from another, but it's a bad design.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The weird thing is that I was running this same script earlier today without issue, but this issue started happening a few hours ago. I don't see anything changed since my last commit, but I must've done anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$psql` is supposed to be an array containing the `psql` command and its arguments.

The script is apparently expected to be run from [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/docker-entrypoint.sh), which does

```
psql=( psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --no-password )
```

and later sources the script in this loop:

```
for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
    case "$f" in
        *.sh)
            # https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/450#issuecomment-393167936
            # https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/pull/452
            if [ -x "$f" ]; then
                echo "$0: running $f"
                "$f"
            else
                echo "$0: sourcing $f"
                . "$f"
            fi
            ;;
        *.sql)    echo "$0: running $f"; "${psql[@]}" -f "$f"; echo ;;
        *.sql.gz) echo "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | "${psql[@]}"; echo ;;
        *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
    esac
    echo
done
```

See [Setting an argument with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash) for the reason to use an array rather than a string.

Comment: It looks like it is run automatically by this script: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/docker-entrypoint.sh So your last point is correct

Comment: Where do you see `initdb-postgis.sh` in that script?

Comment: Never mind, I discovered that it's looping through a directory, and this script should be in it.

Answer (score 2):

The `#!/bin/sh` and the `[@]` are incongruous. This is a bash-ism, where the `psql` variable is an array.  This literal quote dollarsign psql bracket at bracket quote is expanded into "psql" "array" "values" "each" "listed" "and" "quoted" "separately." It's the safer way, e.g., to accumulate arguments to a command where any of them might have spaces in them.

`psql=(/foo/psql arg arg arg)` is the best way to define the array you need there.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Barmar is correct.

The script was intended to be "sourced" and not "executed".

I faced the same problem and came to the same answer after I read that it had been reported here and fixed by "chmod".
https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis/issues/119

Therefore, the fix is to change the permissions.
This can be done either in your git repository:

```
chmod -x initdb-postgis.sh
```

or add a line to your docker file.

```
RUN chmod -x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10_postgis.sh
```

I like to do both so that it is clear to others.
Note: if you are using git on windows then permission can be lost. Therefore, "chmod" in the docker file is needed.

Comment: Adding this line in the Dockerfile was the solution for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It might look obscure, but it would work like so...

Let's say we have a `bash` array `wc`, which contains a command `wc`, and an argument `-w`, and we feed that a *here document* with some words:

```
wc=(wc -w)
"${wc[@]}" <<- words
      one
      two three
      four
words
```

Since there are four words in the *here document*, the output is:

```
4
```

---

In the quoted code, there needs to be some prior point, (perhaps a calling script), that does something like:

```
psql=(psql -option1 -option2 arg1 arg2 ... )
```

---

As to **why** the programmer chose to invoke a  command with an array, rather than just invoke the command, I can only guess...  Maybe it's a crude sort of [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) to compensate for different *nix distros, (*i.e.* BSD vs. Linux), where the local variants of some necessary command might have different names from the same option, or even use different commands.  So one might check for *BSD* or *Linux* or a given version, and reset `psql` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of what the code was actually doing, too! I assumed it was some useful but difficult to read bash-fu :)