# how to pass defaults to flags

Tags: bash, flags

I need to pass defaults to the -c -t -u flags.
in the -c i need that to be infinite
in the -t  i need that to be 1 sec
and in the -u the defauls is ANY user

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u

print_usage(){
echo "usage: script[-c] [-t] [-u] exe-name"
}
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
print_usage
exit 1
fi

while getopts :c:t:u: flag; do
case $flag in
c) counts=$OPTARG;;
t) timeout=$OPTARG;;
u) user_name=$OPTARG;;
esac
done

if [ $counts==true ]
    then
top -n ${counts}
    fi
if [ $timeout==true ]
    then
top -d ${timeout}
    fi
if [ $user_name==true ]
    then
top -u ${user_name}
    fi
```

I tried to put something like that in the biginning but it doesn't work:

```
counts=
timeout=1
user_name=.
```

Comment: `if [ $counts==true ]` should be `if [ $counts = true ]` You need spaces around `=`.

Comment: If `$counts` is supposed to be a number, why are you comparing with `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign default values to the variables before the `while` loop.

Use arrays for variables that can hold multiple arguments. See [Setting an argument with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash) for the reasons.

You can then execute a single `top` command that has all the arguments combined.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u

print_usage(){
    echo "usage: script [-c repetitions] [-t timeout] [-u username] exe-name"
}
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    print_usage
    exit 1
fi

counts=()
timeout=(-d 1)
user_name=()

while getopts :c:t:u: flag; do
    case $flag in
        c) counts=(-n "$OPTARG");;
        t) timeout=(-d "$OPTARG");;
        u) user_name=(-u "$OPTARG");;
    esac
done

top "${counts[@]}" "${timeout[@]}" "${user_name[@]}"
```