# bash script with conditional arguments and output pipe not working

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Can u please help me with bash script for ffmpeg?
Trying to create condition based on args to play OR save media to file, so I've created this kind of IF:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "play" ]; then
    POSTFIX="-f matroska - | mpv -"
else
    POSTFIX="-y $OUTPUT"
fi

ffmpeg \
  # skipped personal ffmpeg stuff
  "$POSTFIX"
```

Now when I try to run it with "play" argument it says:

```
Unrecognized option 'f matroska - | mpv -'.
```

So if I add this POSTFIX both variants to command everything works fine...

It looks like something in my bash screens this args or something like that? Also I don't see in error this dash symbol before f option

Comment: First, see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Second, `| mpv -` is not an argument at all.

Comment: Third (though not as relevant as long as your code really is running only with bash and not sh), `==` is not a standard string comparison operator in `[` -- the only standardized one just a single `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Shell operators are not processed after expanding variables, you would need to use `eval "ffmpeg $POSTFIX"` to do this. But getting all the quoting right for `eval()` will be difficult.

Instead, you can use the `exec` command and redirect its output to the `mpv -` command.

It's also best to put dynamic arguments into an array rather than a string; see [Setting an argument with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "play" ]; then
    POSTFIX=(-f matroska -)
    exec > >(mpv -)
else
    POSTFIX=(-y "$OUTPUT")
fi

ffmpeg "${POSTFIX[@]}"
```

Comment: When did `exec | mpv -` become supported? I think that's pretty new; might it be safer to use `exec > >(mpv -)` instead?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just assumed it was supported, I was wrong