# Splitting a string of bash commands into array of individual commands and command separators

Tags: bash, shell

Say, I have a string `x` which has multiple bash commands chained using command separators. E.g.

```
x="cmd1 2&>1 && cmd2 || cmd3 ; cmd4 | cmd5"
```

Is there a way I can easily split `x` into an array of strings `y` that contains all the individual bash commands and the command separators?

`echo ${y[0]}` --> `cmd1 2&>1`

`echo ${y[1]}` --> `&&`

`echo ${y[2]}` --> `cmd2`

`echo ${y[3]}` --> `||`

`echo ${y[4]}` --> `cmd3`

`echo ${y[5]}` --> `;`

`echo ${y[6]}` --> `cmd4`

`echo ${y[7]}` --> `|`

`echo ${y[8]}` --> `cmd5`

Note, cmd1, cmd2, etc can be any arbitrary bash command, e.g. `./test.sh arg1 arg2` or `/bin/bash -c '...'`

I tried using the IFS splitting method to separate the strings. However, when I set `IFS='&&'`, it ends up splitting on a single `&` too. Example below:

```
> bash -c 'echo $(hostname)' 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && echo hello
hello
> x="bash -c 'echo \$(hostname)' 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && echo hello"
> echo $x
bash -c 'echo $(hostname)' 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && echo hello
> IFS='&&'
> cmds=($x)
> unset IFS
> echo ${cmds[0]}
bash -c 'echo $(hostname)' 1>/dev/null 2>
> echo ${cmds[1]}
1
> echo ${cmds[2]}

> echo ${cmds[3]}
echo hello
> echo ${cmds[@]}
bash -c 'echo $(hostname)' 1>/dev/null 2> 1 echo hello
```

As you can see above, IFS doesn't work when the separator is multiple characters.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: No, there's nothing simple for parsing shell commands.

Comment: A prime example is `'echo \$(hostname)'` -- which will be word-split into `'echo` and `\$(hostname)'` unless you modify `IFS`. But, the point @Barmar is making is there is no simple way to handle all the caveats of what may be part of your `x=` and split that into an array where each element gets a command. Especially where you have whitespace in some of your commands. The time to handle separating the parts of `x=` is **before** the assignment to `x` is made.

Comment: Anyway, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Note also that you don't even need whitespace delimiters. Many shell operators are delimiters by themselves. Your command can be written as `cmd1 2&>1&&cmd2||cmd3;cmd4|cmd5`.

Comment: And you'll need to deal with quoting, and grouping with `{}` and `()`.

Comment: `x="a=\; b='||' <c >d $(printf '%s\n' e f | sort -r)"` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can easily split x into an array of strings y that contains all the individual bash commands and the command separators?

No.

> Any ideas?

*You* have to write a parser for shell grammar or you can use an existing one. You may be interested in Bash and busybox ash and other shell sources and in shellcheck project.

Note: Completely unrelated to your program, when you want to store a command or chain of commands in something that can be executed or serialized, you should use a function. If you want to store command arguments in a variable, you should use a bash array. Related: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

Comment: Insetead of linking to an external site, how about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash