# How is $cmd different from eval $cmd?

Tags: bash, shell

Consider this little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="ls -rtl $1"
$cmd
eval $cmd
```

It prints the directory listing with some option set (just to make it different from a simple ls), twice.
Both of the last two lines do the same thing, apparently. Is there some case, that I am not considering?

Why bother writing eval in front of the cmd?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for an extensive discussion of exactly how and why `$cmd` is broken.

Comment: They're different if `$cmd` contains shell metacharacters.

Comment: (and if `$1` is a wildcard and the command is run in a directory where filenames aren't under the operator's control, `eval $cmd` is outright a major security risk)

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/048](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365553/setting-an-argument-with-bash

Comment: `eval $cmd` is _also_ broken. It needs to be `eval "$cmd"` **with the quotes** to be safe and correct (assuming that the value of the variable `$cmd` is itself known to be safe and correct, which it isn't when you substitute the value of `$1` into it as shown in the question; a less-bad alternative would be `cmd='ls -rtl "$1"'`, which defers that substitution until the last time the command goes through the parser).

Comment: ...with bash 5.0, you could also use `cmd="ls -rtl ${1@Q}"` to make something safe to `eval`, or with older versions, `printf -v cmd 'ls -rtl %q' "$1"`

Comment: Generally speaking, *don't* write `eval` in front of `$cmd`.  Or ever.  Ignore this advice, after adequate consideration, only when you thoroughly understand why I am giving it.

Comment: Since you asked for an example of where the two would make a difference: Do a `cmd='echo $HOME'` and then try `$cmd` and `eval $cmd`.